# How do I deploy a function in python with its dependencies?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to use the `serverless` framework to create and deploy an AWS Lambda function. I created a folder named `vendored` in the root of the project and installed (using `pip install`) the function dependencies. However, whenever I try to run it (using `serverless function run`) I got an error:

> Serverless: Running isNewUser...
>   Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: region
>   Serverless: -----------------
>   Serverless: Failed - This Error Was Returned:
>   Serverless: {"exception": ["Traceback (most recent call last):\n", "  File \"/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler\", line 170, in \n    handler = import_program_as_module(path)\n", "  File \"/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler\", line 149, in import_program_as_module\n    module = make_module_from_file('lambda_handler', handler_file)\n", "  File \"/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler\", line 129, in make_module_from_file\n    py_source_description\n", "  File \"/home/fernando/workspace/os-cac/isNewUser/handler.py\", line 11, in \n    from vtex.order import Order\n", "ImportError: No module named vtex.order\n"], "success": false}
>   Serverless: Exception message from Python
>   Serverless: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ,  File "/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler", line 170, in 
>       handler = import_program_as_module(path)
>   ,  File "/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler", line 149, in import_program_as_module
>       module = make_module_from_file('lambda_handler', handler_file)
>   ,  File "/home/fernando/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/serverless-run-python-handler", line 129, in make_module_from_file
>       py_source_description
>   ,  File "/home/fernando/workspace/os-cac/isNewUser/handler.py", line 11, in 
>       from vtex.order import Order
>   ,ImportError: No module named vtex.order
>   `

`vtex.order` is a module imported in handler.py

The structure of my project is something like:

```
/root/
     |
     |--_meta/
     |--vendored/
                |--dependencies...
     |--function-name/
                     |--handler.py
                     |--event.json
                     |--s-function.json
     |--requirements.txt
     |--admin.env
     |--package.json
     |--s-project.json
     |--s-resources-cf.json
     |--s-project.json
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Should I somehow  configure my function to include the dependencies from vendored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few steps that should make it work:

1. Make sure that the handler entry in `s-function.json` has the function-name in its path:
   `"handler": "function-name/handler.handler",`
2. in `handler.py` add the following:

   ```
   import os
   import sys

   here = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(here, "../vendored"))

   from vtex.order import Order
   ```

That's it. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Be aware that the libraries you vendor into the serverless package may not work in the AWS Lambda environment.  This is usually only true for non-pure-Python libraries like cryptography, cffi and others.  If you run into that, you can either pick up libraries from a resource like https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages, or you can do the pip installs on a Linux machine that's close enough to Amazon Linux (I used centos 6-x64) and copy out of the site-packages directory that populates.  If anyone needs more details, respond here and I'll add a question & answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. But, is there a PEP 8 compliant way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 4):

I followed below steps to deploy with dependencies:

- Created a directory for dependencies in project root `mkdir .vendor`
- Add dependencies in requirements.txt file manually or use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Update serverless.yml file

`package:
  include:
    - .vendor/**`

- Include .vendor directory to system path in handler.py file

`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './.vendor')`

- Install dependencies `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .vendor`

Now `serverless deploy` will upload function with dependencies.

Comment: Oh wow.  sys path munging makes me feel dirty. Surely there is a better way.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) plugin to include packages installed via `pip`

Comment: Except that it blows up on hitting the setup.py of a project brought in via github.  Not fun. See https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6495#