# How to import Python dependencies in Serverless v1.0

Tags: python, serverless-framework

Language: Python
Framework: [Serverless](https://serverless.com) v1.0

Typically I would run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the project root

How can I get these dependencies packaged into every deploy?

Answer (score 12):

1. create `requirements.txt`

   pip freeze > requirements.txt
2. create a folder with all the dependencies:

   pip install -t vendored -r requirements.txt

Note that in order to use these dependencies in the code you'll need to add the following:

```
import os
import sys
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(here, "./vendored"))
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944792/1111215 for another example.

---

**UPDATE:** Instead of the bullet (2) and the code above, you can now use the [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) plugin:

install the plugin

```
npm install --save serverless-python-requirements
```

and add the plugin to your `serverless.yml`

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

Don't forget to make sure you have a `requirements.txt` file.

That's it, once `sls deploy` is called the plugin will package the dependencies with the code.

For a full sample take a look at the [serverless-python-sample](https://github.com/bennybauer/serverless-python-sample).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, took these steps to deploy with dependencies.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634501/2571060