# Serverless Framework - Python and Requirements.txt

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Using the serverless framework v1.0.0, I have a 'requirements.txt' in my service root with the contents being the list of dependant python packages. (e.g. requests).

However my resulting deployed function fails as it seems these dependencies are not installed as part of the packaging

'Unable to import module 'handler': No module named requests'

I assume it is serverless that does the pip install, but my resulting zip file is small and clearly its not doing it, either by design or my fault as I am missing something?  Is it because its Lambda that does this?  If so what am I missing?)

Is there documentation on what is required to do this and how it works?  Is it serverless that pip installs these or on aws lambda side?

Comment: I don't think serverless runs pip. You have to run that yourself before you deploy your serverless project.

Comment: detailed guide below https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027031/1085343

Answer (score 31):

You need to install `serverless-python-requirements` and [docker](https://www.docker.com)

```
$ npm install serverless-python-requirements
```

Then add the following to your `serverless.yml`

```
plugins:
   - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
     dockerizePip: non-linux
```

Make sure you have your python virtual environment active in CLI:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Install any dependencies with pip - note that in CLI you can tell if venv is active by the `venv` to the left of the terminal text

```
(venv) $ pip install <NAME>
(venv) $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Make sure you have opened docker then deploy serverless as normal

```
$ serverless deploy
```

What will happen is that `serverless-python-requirements` will build you python packages in docker using a lambda environment, and then zip them up ready to be uploaded with the rest of your code.

[Full guide here](https://serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb/#using-the-quick-start-template)

Comment: If you are having trouble with the `$ serverless deploy` command, you might have to remove the redundant node_modules that might have worked in the past as was in my case. I had to do the following commands: 
```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm install serverless-python-requirements
$ serverless deploy
```

Comment: +1 for `source venv/bin/active` - wouldn't have thought it would have been an issue when deploying but apparently it is! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Now you can use [serverless-python-requirements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements). It works both for pure Python and libraries needing native compilation (using Docker):

A Serverless v1.x plugin to automatically bundle dependencies from requirements.txt and make them available in your PYTHONPATH.

Requires Serverless >= v1.12

Answer (score 0):

The Serverless Framework doesn't handle the `pip install`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791686/1111215 for the solution