# AWS Lambda and python numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda

I am trying to import a python deployment package in aws lambda. The python code uses numpy. I followed the deployment package instructions for virtual env but it still gave Missing required dependencies ['numpy']. I followed the instruction given on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda) (skipped step 4 for shared libraries, could not find any shared libraries) but no luck. Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your lambda function?

Comment: whats your project structure look like ? it could be just how you are zipping your package. also have you pre-compiled 'numpy' ?

Comment: The project folder contains *.py files, all the files of site-packages and files and folders from dist-package. I am not sure what pre-compilation of numpy means. I guess I am not zipping it correctly but not sure what I am doing wrong. Should I only include dist-packages and not site-packages? Should I include all the folders with files within or copy all the files from different folders at the same place?

Comment: @user1484793 hey, have you solved your problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use AWS Cloud9, there is no need to start EC2 instances and prepare deployment packages.

### Step 1: start up Cloud9 IDE

- Go to the AWS console and select the Cloud9 service.
- Create environment
- enter Name
- Environment settings (consider using t2.small instance type, with the default I had sometimes problems to restart the environment)
- Review
- click Create environment

### Step 2: create Lambda function

- Create Lambda Function (bottom of screen)
- enter Function name and Application name
- Select runtime (Python 3.6) and blueprint (empty-python)
- Function trigger (none)
- Create serverless application (keep defaults)
- Finish
- wait couple of seconds for the IDE to open

### Step 3: install Numpy

- at the bottom of the screen there is a command prompt
- go to the Application folder, for me this is

  ```
  cd App
  ```
- install the package (we have to use pip from the virtual environment, because the default pip points to /usr/bin/pip and this is python 2.7)

  ```
  venv/bin/pip install numpy -t .
  ```

### Step4: test installation

- you can test the installation by editing the lambda_function.py file:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
      return np.sin(1.0)
  ```
- save the changes and click the green Run button on the top of the screen
- a new tab should appear, now click the green Run button inside the tab
- after the Lambda executes I get:

  ```
  Response
  0.8414709848078965
  ```

### Step 5: deploy Lambda function

- on the right hand side of the screen select your Lambda function
- click the upwards pointing arrow to deploy
- go to the AWS Lambda service tab
- the Lambda function should be visible, the name has the format

  ```
  cloud9-ApplicationName-FunctionName-RandomString
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy is a real pain.

Numpy needs to be properly compiled on the same OS as it runs. This means that you need to install/compile Numpy on an AMI image in order for it erun properly in Lambda.

The easiest way to do this is to start a small EC2 instance and install it there. Then copy the compiled files (from /usr/lib/python/site-packages/numpy). These are the files you need to include in your Lambda package.

I believe you can also use the [serverless](https://serverless.com/) tool to achieve this.

Comment: This is what I do, and it works. But don't forget to extract the linear algebra shared objects out of the EC2 instance and include them in a `lib/` dir in your Lambda package `ZIP` contents. I.e. AWS Lambda de facto includes `$LAMBDA_ROOT/lib/` in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy must be compiled on the platform that it will be run on. Easiest way to do this is to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Docker has a lambda container. Compile NumPy locally in Docker with the lambda container, then push to AWS lambda.

The [serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework handles all this for you if you want an easy solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027031/1085343

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and pip install wasn't working for me. Eventually, I found some obscure posts about this issue [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/) and [here](https://conceptual.io/#/post/resolving-dependency-issues-in-aws-cloud9). They suggested going to pypi, downloading the .whl file (select py version and manylinux1_x86_64), uploading, and unzipping. This is what ultimately worked for me. If nothing else is working for you, I would suggest trying this.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3.6, you can use a Docker image as someone already suggested.  Full instructions for that here:  https://medium.com/i-like-big-data-and-i-cannot-lie/how-to-create-an-aws-lambda-python-3-6-deployment-package-using-docker-d0e847207dd6

The key piece is:

docker run -it dacut/amazon-linux-python-3.6