# Using numpy in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I'm looking for a work around to use numpy in AWS lambda. I am not using EC2 just lambda for this so if anyone has a suggestion that'd be appreciated. Currently getting the error:

cannot import name 'multiarray'

Using grunt lambda to create the zip file and upload the function code. All the modules that I use are installed into a folder called python_modules inside the root of the lambda function which includes numpy using pip install and a requirements.txt file.

Comment: You should probably have your modules installed or symlinked directly  to the root of your Lambda function package. And make sure that all the dependencies also go there.

Comment: I know what you're getting at but all the modules work fine as the env variable points to them.

Comment: Did you solve this issue by any chance? I have the exact issue on Python 3.6?

Comment: I haven't gotten back to it, but i did find this link althought i haven't had a chance to look back into it! Hopefully you get something out of this and if you do let me know!   https://github.com/vitolimandibhrata/aws-lambda-numpy .  From my understanding it takes complete versions of numpy packages and you can drop them into your project.

Comment: As of 2018 it's best and easiest to use layers: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/ AWS even have premade one for numpy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated to include the solution here, rather than a link:

After much effort, I found that I had to create my deployment package **from within a python3.6 virtualenv**, rather than directly from the host machine. I did the following within a Ubuntu 16.04 docker image. This assumes that you have python3.6, virtualenv and awscli already installed/configured, and that your lambda function code is in the ~/lambda_code directory:

1) `cd ~` (We'll build the virtualenv in the home directory)

2) `virtualenv venv --python=python3.6` (Create the virtual environment)

3) `source venv/bin/activate` (Activate the virtual environment)

4) `pip install numpy`

5) `cp -r ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/* ~/lambda_code` (Copy all installed packages into root level of lambda_code directory. This will include a few unnecessary files, but you can remove those yourself if needed)

6) `cd ~/lambda_code`

7) `zip -r9 ~/package.zip .` (Zip up the lambda package)

8) `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_function --zip-file fileb://~/package.zip` (Upload to AWS)

Your lambda function should now be able to import numpy with no problems.

If you want a more out-of-the-box solution, you could consider using serverless to deploy your lambda function. Before I found the above solution, I followed the guide [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) and was able to run numpy successfully in a python3.6 lambda function.

Comment: you can save yourself some time by using Docker and/or Serverless framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859497/aws-lambda-and-python-numpy-module/50270737#50270737

Answer (score 11):

**An easy way** to make your lambda function support the numpy library for python 3.7:

1. Go to your lambda function page
2. Find the Layers section at the bottom of the page.
3. Click on Add a layer.
4. Choose AWS layers as layer source.
5. Select AWSLambda-Python37-Scipy1x as AWS layers.
6. Select 37 for version.
7. And finally click on Add.

Now your lambda function is ready to support numpy.

Comment: Numpy can be added with the layer "AWSDataWrangler-Python39" (I don't see the layer mentioned above. )

Comment: @DaveP Maybe your Python version was different from mine.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 it's best to just use the inbuilt layers functionality.

AWS have actually released a pre-made one with numpy in it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a good solution using serverless plugins, but I did find a good way with layers.  See [Serverless - Numpy - Unable to find good bind path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936747/serverless-numpy-unable-to-find-good-bind-path-format)

Answer (score 0):

Add numpy layer in this way:

- Go on your lambda function
- select add a new layer
- add it using this arn: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p39-numpy:7

(change your zone if you are not in eu-central-1)

Let me know if it will work

Answer (score -1):

1.) Do a Pip install of numpy to a folder on your local machine.

2.) once complete, zip the entire folder and create a zip file.

3.) Go to AWS lambda console, create a layer and upload zip file created in step 2 there and save the layer.

4.) After you create your lambda function, click add layer and add the layer you created. That's it, import numpy will start working.

Answer (score -1):

#### Title:

[Problem] Issue with dependencies while using Matplotlib and NumPy in AWS Lambda

#### ISSUES :

{
"errorMessage": "module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'",
"errorType": "AttributeError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
"  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
"  File "", line 702, in _load\n",
"  File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
"  File "", line 843, in exec_module\n",
"  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 3, in \n    import numpy as np\n",
"  File "/opt/python/numpy/**init**.py", line 112, in \n    _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2()\n",
"  File "/opt/python/numpy/**init**.py", line 109, in _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2\n    os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)\n"
]
}

#### Description:

I encountered an issue while trying to use Matplotlib and NumPy in an AWS Lambda function. Despite specifying specific versions of dependencies, I kept encountering errors related to missing modules or incompatible versions. After troubleshooting, I found a solution that resolved the issue.

#### Solution:

After thorough investigation, I discovered that the problem was caused by incompatible dependencies. To resolve the issue, I downgraded certain dependencies to specific versions that are known to work well together.

#### Dependencies:

- certifi==2019.6.16
- cftime==1.0.3.4
- chardet==3.0.4
- cycler==0.10.0
- idna==2.8
- kiwisolver==1.1.0
- matplotlib==3.1.1
- netCDF4==1.5.1.2
- numpy==1.17.1
- pyparsing==2.4.2
- python-dateutil==2.8.0
- requests==2.22.0
- six==1.12.0
- urllib3==1.25.3

#### Tested Environment:

- Local development environment (mac os, Python 3.8)
- AWS Lambda

#### Tags:

python, matplotlib, numpy, dependencies, aws-lambda

#### Feedback:

I'm open to feedback on this solution or alternative approaches that others would recommend. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.