# serverless-python-requirements not working

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a "hello-world" python project with serverless framework.
I'm trying to deploy a simple lambda function that needs numpy. But currently, when I run `sls deploy` and try to call the lambda function, I get an `internal server error`.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
test_api/
    serverless.yml
    test_api.py
    Pipfile
```

in `test.py` I have:

```
import numpy as np


def handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": f"numpy version = {np.__version__}"
    }
```

In my `serverless.yml`:

```
service: test_api
frameworkVersion: "3"
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: eu-west-3
  stage: dev

functions:
  test:
    handler: tes_api.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: test_api
          method: get
          cors: true

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

In Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
numpy = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

When I deploy, I have no error, but when I call the end point, I get:
[image]

When I test it on AWS:
[image: AWS_test_lambda]

If I remove numpy from Pipfile and lambda (I just return "hello" in my lambda), everything works fine.

**Why do I get this error and how can I fix it ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185297/using-numpy-in-aws-lambda

Comment: @MarkB Thank for the answer but i picked numpy as an example. I have the same probleme for psychog2 or any other library. The plugin serverless-python-requirements is supposed to work with Pipfile according to the documentation of serverless framework:
https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements
https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo in your serverless.yml file?

you have

```
handler: tes_api.handler
```

I imagine it's meant to be test_api.handler

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of your project, it seems you missed an important step mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements) - no `package.json`. You need to run the following command in your project directory:

```
$ sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
```

> This will automatically add the plugin to your project's `package.json` and the plugins section of its `serverless.yml`.

If you want to start from the beginning, then run the following commands in your active `venv` of your project directory:

```
$ npm init
```

then

```
$ npm install --save serverless-python-requirements
```

I would add the following to your `serverless.yml`

```
# serverless.yml

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

Then deploy while your `venv` is active.
Please note `serverless-python-requirements` requires Docker for it to work.