# Cannot import layers in aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing a lambda function with python3.6. It uses pytesseract library to convert image to text. I created layer with below folder structure.

```
python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL
python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Pillow-6.2.1.dist-info
python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract
python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract-0.3.1.dist-info
```

Compressed 'python' folder (as shown above) and uploaded to layers in AWS.

My lambda function code is as below. My code is in python3.6

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image002.jpg')))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

But when I run code I get below error

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'
```

This error is because it is unable to find pillow library (PIL). But it is already included in site-packages folder. I believe there would be some mistake folder structure of layers.

I already tried with folder strutures as guided in below links but no success:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711008/1030951

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: did you ger any solution? I am facing the same issue. @HarshIT

Comment: @Jyotirmay , I have added my answer below.

Comment: Pretty late, though I upvoted it. I think I did some workaround to solve that issue back then. haahaa. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research I found that the PIL library uses C code internally and that is not directly supported in lambda function for python environment so I was unable to import PIL in that function. Proper solution is to go with ECS and deploy my own Docker image to perform such operation.

Answer (score -2):

download the library PIL using --target option in pip install and place that lib file in lambda zip file and then upload it.

`pip install --target drive/location PIL`

This solution is without using layers.

Comment: I recently tried with that structure as well, Still the same error. see my folder structure screenshot in this link: https://pasteboard.co/IMHDKnA.png

Comment: Then this error is not because of the PIL package. It says - `unable to import module lambda_function` .  There might be error in lambda configuration.

Comment: well it is ' unable to import module lambda_function' because it is "unable to import name _imaging''. The entire error message is like this