# how to name uploaded directory in serverless framework?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am building an application with AWS lambda and the serverless framework. My folder structure looks like this when deployed:

```
service-dev-lambdaname (name of top level dir)
|__lib
|__serverless.yml
|__python-library-1
|__python-library-2
|__src
    |__lambda
```

When I run `serverless deploy`, it correctly packages and uploads my service. It uses the naming convention `{service name}-dev-{function name}`. This is not the name of the parent folder locally so it is messing up the imports. I thought that instead, I should move everything into `src` but the serverless plugin packages libraries like `python-library-1` and `python-library-2` and places them outside `src`. Is there a way to change the naming convention to fix these import errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use python `pip` locally within your projects python `venv` to install your packages. Make sure you have Docker installed, then when you run `serverless deploy` it will use docker to package up your python libs to be correctly deployed in lambda.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027031/1085343