# No module named pymysql - aws serverless framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, pymysql

I deployed a python lambda function through server less framework. Installed `pymysql` through `pip`. My handler info is : `dynamodbtoauroradb/aurora-data-management/aurora-data-management.handler`

[image]

I get this error:
`Unable to import module 'dynamodbtoauroradb/aurora-data-management/aurora-data-management': No module named 'pymysql'`

Not sure where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that pymysql is there in your system packages. So when you built the virtualenvironment, it used the system package.

Create a clean virtualenv using

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages envname
```

Or else you can use the current one, with

```
pip install pymysql --no-deps --ignore-installed
```

Comment: Assuming you tried both options above and redeployed to lambda after each try

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin [serverless-python-requirements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements) with docker.

This will package all your python virtual env dependencies into your serverless package.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027031/1085343) for more details