# Asyncpg and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asyncpg

I'm trying to use asyncpg with AWS Lambda and got next error when trying to `import asyncpg`

```
Unable to import module 'handler': No module named asyncpg.protocol.protocol'
```

I import python dependencies like at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791686/4542977) answer with and without virtual environment.

upd. Found [this](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) repo with custom compiled `psycopg2` what works good with AWS Lambda but for `asyncpg` don't found such alternative or instruction on compiling Lambda-friendly `asyncpg` package.

Answer (score 4):

This library has c-bindings and lambda does not play nicely with those.
The main way to handle it is to upload the specific library with its bindings precompiled for Linux environments.
The main way to is to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) and make sure that the library it already compiled in your linux ( or mac I guess ). This would easily happen by just creating a venv and including it as the above guidelines suggest.
You can find a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda).
In general,  this is a common and frameworks like [chalice](https://github.com/awslabs/chalice) try to find some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

write your code under the `def lambdahandler()` and also import all libraries and function  below this function.